# How do I add a 'previous chapter' and 'next chapter' link in documentation generated by Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

When I look at documentation, the most pages have a previous chapter and next chapter link/button at the bottom, for example [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I can't find out how to accomplish this for my project documentation using the [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) documentation tool. Could someone tell me how this works or point me to a useful resource (although I already searched a lot)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [sphinx-doc.org](http://sphinx-doc.org) documentation on templating mentions the `next` and `prev` variables:

> The next document for the navigation. This variable is either false or
>   has two attributes link and title. The title contains HTML markup. For
>   example, to generate a link to the next page, you can use this
>   snippet:

```
{% if next %}
    <a href="{{ next.link|e }}">{{ next.title }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

See more at: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/templating.html#next

You can use them anywhere in your Sphinx template and style with CSS accordingly.

---

A full example might be:

```
<ul class="footer_nav">
    {%- if prev %}
      <li class="prev">
        Previous topic: <a href="{{ prev.link|e }}">{{ prev.title }}</a>
      </li>
    {%- endif %}

    {%- if next %}
      <li class="next">
        Next topic: <a href="{{ next.link|e }}">{{ next.title }}</a>
      </li>
    {%- endif %}
</ul>
```

Comment: The link has changed to https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/templating.html#next