# Sphinx custom template

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I want to add a "next" and "previous" button at the bottom of my page.

I saw a similar question posted ["here"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260726/how-do-i-add-a-previous-chapter-and-next-chapter-link-in-documentation-gener)

But he doesn't explain which file to edit and where.

Should I edit the conf.py file and copy paste the code in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are themes that provide that functionality out of the box. You could install Sphinx bootstrap theme, which is a nice looking theme with bootstrap integration. You can find it here: https://ryan-roemer.github.io/sphinx-bootstrap-theme/

Other solution: just follow the link you posted and do what the accepted answer suggests.

Comment: the problem is that I dont know which file to edit. were is the file? What is the name of the file? Im using "read the docs" template on ubuntu

Comment: PythonXX/Lib/site-packages/sphinx_rtd_theme

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx_rtd_theme